# What data types can be bound to a .Net DataGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable, datagrid

We have a DataTable with three DataColumns of DataTypes Int32, String and KeyValuePair. After populating the DataTable it is then bound to a .Net DataGrid for display in a webapp. After binding, the Column with the DataType KeyValuePair is NOT bound. The DataGrid only displays two columns of data - the Int32 and String columns.

In our ItemDataBound event handler we can see the DataSource is the DataTable described above and the DataGrid only binds two columns.

Any ideas why only two columns are bound? Is it documented anywhere which DataTypes are valid for binding to a DataGrid?

Thanks in advance.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("TestTable");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(Int32));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(KeyValuePair<string, string>));
        DataRow dr = dt1.NewRow();
        dr["Column1"] = 1;
        dr["Column2"] = "Hello World";
        dr["Column3"] = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "Hello World");
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
        dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dg.DataSource = dt;
        dg.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't think the problem here is any "type restriction". The problem is most likely that you placed a `KeyValuePair` inside a `DataTable` column... and now, because you're using `AutoGenerateColumns=true`, it probably doesn't know what to do with it... Solution? You're going to need to manually add `<asp:BoundColumn/>`, which in the case of your column 3 will contain whatever it is that your object's `ToString()` prints out. In the case of a `KeyValuePair`, [it will look something like this](https://imgur.com/M4ClNme).

Comment: @jsanalytics - your insight turned out to be correct. I needed to set AutoGenerateColumns=false and manually bind the columns in the DataGrid to the columns in the DataTable. "Manually binding" meant creating the columns in the DataGrid with the same name as their respective column in the DataTable. Can you add you suggestion as the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer, always happy to help anyone i can. Cheers !